# How to persist image in mysql database using Spring MVC and JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa

This is my imageForm.jsp:

```
%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Image Form</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="/showImage">
  Picture: <input type="file" name="image">
  <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is showImage.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Show Image</h2>

<p>Profile Picture : ${image.image}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my controller:

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import java.util.List;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/imageForm")
    public ModelAndView showImageForm(Model model) {

        return new ModelAndView("imageForm", "command", new Image());
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showImage")
    public ModelAndView showResult(@ModelAttribute("")Image image, ModelAndView model) {

        model.setViewName("showImage");
        System.out.println("Transaction");
        em.persist(image);
        System.out.println("persisted");
        model.addObject("image", image);
        return model;
    }
}
```

This is the Image.java model class:

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Image {
    @Id
    private int imageID;
    private byte[] image;

    public int getImageID() {
        return imageID;
    }

    public void setImageID(int imageID) {
        this.imageID = imageID;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

And the persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="NewPersistenceUnit">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.springapp.mvc.Image</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/advocatoree"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I can choose an image from my PC and when I press the submit button, the showImage.jsp page shows me this: `Profile Picture : [B@1c6a19f`

The entry is persisted in database, but under the image attribute, it shows: `[BLOB - 39 B]`
If I click on it, I get a .bin file downloaded. I don't how I should approach this problem, can someone please help me?

Comment: and where is the "Image" class and its JPA mapping?

Comment: I think you have to get the image aka file as `MultiPartFile` and from that object take the info and the image itself. see here http://www.just-thor.com/2014/03/01/spring-mvc-and-jpa-upload-and-retrieve-photo-to-postgres/

Comment: I have made edits in my question. You can check out my model class and persistence.xml now.

Comment: and is it persisted correctly? and is it retrieved from JPA correctly?

Comment: Yes for both the questions. I can see that the data has been persisted in the database but I think it cannot quite figure out the datatype. (Blob in the database)

Comment: so why haven't you marked the byte array field as @Blob ??? and "what" cannot figure out the datatype?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it - save the picture in any working directory using **FileOutputStream**, in db you can save unique picture name or path to it. Also you shall receive from the client byte[] in **base64 format**. The problem may be that you get an byte array represented as string (like "asd561$%@!"), then use **Base64.getDecoder().decode(your_string).**